# How to write prepareStatement in Java

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc

i want to use `getParameter` to get in `String`s and `int`s and put them in a database using `prepareStatement` and SQL. It gives me errors with `setString` and `setInt`.

```
try {
    String id = request.getParameter("clientid");
    String cname = request.getParameter("clientname");
    String address = request.getParameter("address");
    String phonemodel= request.getParameter("phonemodel");
    String imei = request.getParameter("imei");
    String problem = request.getParameter("problem");
    String date2 = request.getParameter("date");
    String comments1= request.getParameter("comments");

    int  clientid = Integer.parseInt(id);
    int imeino  = Integer.parseInt(imei);
    // int date1 = Integer.parseInt(date2);

    Statement pstmt;

    Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"); 
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sample", "app" , "app");

    pstmt=con.prepareStatement("Insert into movilapp(id,clientname,address,modle,imei,problem,date,comments) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    pstmt.setInt(1,clientid);
    pstmt.setString(2,cname );
    pstmt.setString(3,address);
    pstmt.setString(4,phonemodel);
    pstmt.setInt(5,imeino);
    pstmt.setString(6,problem);
    pstmt.setString(7, comments1);
    pstmt.executeUpdate();
}
catch(Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You called `con.prepareStatement` to get a `PreparedStatement`, but then you assigned it to a variable of type `Statement`, so Java doesn't know that there is a `PreparedStatement`-specific method `setString`.

Assign it to an actual `PreparedStatement` variable, by changing the declaration type of pstmt from

```
Statement pstmt;
```

to

```
PreparedStatement pstmt;
```

Answer (score 1):

****IF Use `Statement` Then its syntax is   ****

```
 Statement stmt = null;
 stmt = conn.createStatement( );
 String sql = "UPDATE Employees set age=30 WHERE id=103";
 stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
```

And for `PreparedStatement` it is

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
String SQL = "Update Employees SET age = ? WHERE id = ?";
pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(SQL);
psmt.setInt(1,30);
psmt.setInt(2,1003);
psmt.executeUpdate(SQL);
```

So change `Statement pstmt;` to `PreparedStatement pstmt = null;` And it will work.